# Here Map stacks in Bootstraps Modal

Tags: here-api

I have several modal buttons which on click should show pre-saved Map Route in PolyLine.
Below code I used on php Ajax Modal Call. $jsline, $center_lat, $center_lng are php variable which are determined on modal click by ajax query.

```
<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:450px"></div>
<script>
    $(document).on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
        function addPolylineToMap(map) {
            var lineString = new H.geo.LineString();
            '.$jsline.'
            map.addObject(new H.map.Polyline(
                lineString, { style: { lineWidth: 4 }}
            ));
        }
        var platform = new H.service.Platform({
            apikey: myhereapi
        });
        var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
        var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
                    defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,{
                    center: {lat:'.$center_lat.', lng:'.$center_lng.'},
                    zoom: 5.65,
                    pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
                });
        window.addEventListener("resize", () => map.getViewPort().resize());
        var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));
        var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);
        addPolylineToMap(map);
    });
</script>
```

If I remove `on("shown.bs.modal")` modal window pops up with blank map (white background, no map). When I use `on("shown.bs.modal")` modal window pops up and work properly on first click. However, second, third, and further clicks will stack maps. I mean in second click there 2 maps appear. In third click 3 maps appear.
Why maps get stacked ? How to resolve this issue ? As far as I can see no one else faced with similar problem before.

[image: First Click Screenshot]

[image: Second Click Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find solution, so I am sharing it if anyone else faces with such issue.
I have added `$("#map").empty();` just before new instance of map is loaded as below.

```
<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:450px"></div>
<script>
    $(document).on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
        function addPolylineToMap(map) {
            var lineString = new H.geo.LineString();
            '.$jsline.'
            map.addObject(new H.map.Polyline(
                lineString, { style: { lineWidth: 4 }}
            ));
        }
        $("#map").empty();
        var platform = new H.service.Platform({
            apikey: myhereapi
        });
        var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
        var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
                    defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,{
                    center: {lat:'.$center_lat.', lng:'.$center_lng.'},
                    zoom: 5.65,
                    pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
                });
        window.addEventListener("resize", () => map.getViewPort().resize());
        var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));
        var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);
        addPolylineToMap(map);
    });
</script>
```